# jquery selecting div id within div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Through jquery I am trying to target a div with an id within a div container with a different id. Example:

```
<div id="container-type-a">
<div id="inner_number_2201"></div> //<<<< this id is a passed dynamic ID and changes. Its passed into the function. 
</div>
```

So I would want to do something like `document.getElementById('> container-type-a' > 'inner_number_' + id + )`
but this is not the right syntax. Can something like this be done?

Comment: getElementById does not contain a selector..... That would be querySelector

Comment: ko thanks so what is the correct when I need to target a div with an id and an inner div with an id

Comment: `document.getElementById("inner_number_" + id_In_Restaurant)`

Comment: right but that only gets one of the two needed. I need to target both the inner and the container id

Comment: You need to reference both elements? You would need to select the one by the id, and than reference the parent.

Comment: ok and how do I reference the parent if not by ID as well?

Answer (score 1):

ID should be unique in the HTML, so unless your HTML is malformed, you should be able to just

```
document.getElementById(id_In_Restaurant)
```

Comment: thanks but it is a div inside of a div, both have an id

Comment: Unless you have multiple elements with the same ID, which you shouldn't, it should still work. Nesting won't be a problem if your HTML is valid.

Comment: the inner div can sometime be in other containers and for the sake of the simplicity of the question, I didnt get into all the other code and why it matters. I only asked the relevant question. I must be able to target both target since they word as a pair

Comment: If a different element with the same ID can exist elsewhere, then your HTML is invalid, which is the problem.

Comment: thanks dont think I formatted this question well so I will rethink and try again. I do appreciate you taking the time

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code if your dynamic div is direct decedent.

```
$('#'+$('#container-type-a >div').attributes.id.value)
```

Comment: thanks dont think I formatted this question well so I will rethink and try again. I do appreciate you taking the time

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a selector, you would use querySelector

```
var inner = document.querySelector("#container-type-a #inner_number_" + id_In_Restaurant);
```

But since ids are supposed to be unique, it makes no sense to use two ids. Just been to use getElementById

```
var inner = document.getElementById("inner_number_" + id_In_Restaurant);
```

Getting a reference to the parent element

```
var inner = document.getElementById("inner_number_" + id_In_Restaurant);
var innersParent = inner.parentElement;
```

Comment: thanks dont think I formatted this question well so I will rethink and try again. I do appreciate you taking the time

Answer (score 1):

Since Id is unique throughout the document so you can use the following syntax

```
$('#inner_number_' + unique_dynamic_id)
```

This will return you the jquery object of the element.

Comment: thanks dont think I formatted this question well so I will rethink and try again. I do appreciate you taking the time